# How statically NAT multiple connections to a single IP address in iptables

Tags: iptables

I have been using ipfilter in the past. Here is what I used there:

```
map-block tun0 192.168.1.0/24 -> 20.20.20.0/24
```

Some remote applications require that multiple connections all come from the same IP address. So, I want to tell iptables to have a static mapping between IP address and use the same IP address for a host (i.e. use some magic to choose a port). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the iptables SNAT target with the `persistent` option to keep the IP chosen for a specific client the same:

`iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 --source 192.168.1.0/24 --jump SNAT --to-source 20.20.20.0/24 --persistent`

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar with netfilter:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to 20.20.20.0/24
```

You can read the `iptables` NAT howto [here](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//NAT-HOWTO.html).

Answer (score 1):

See iptables -j SNAT --to-source [ipaddr[-ipaddr]] --persistent

I don't know though "how static" this is. Maybe the mapping is lost on reboot. If that is a problem then you might configure a static mapping by an explicit rule for each address.

IIRC there is a tool (unfortunately I cannot remember the name) which can map source or destination addresses to chains so that you don't need a chain with 254 entries:

```
iptables ... -s 192.168.1.1 -j ...
iptables ... -s 192.168.1.2 -j ...
iptables ... -s 192.168.1.3 -j ...
```